# How can I make Nuxt.js accept both `/` and `/index.html` URL?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.js default mode, universal and history router.

When I run `nuxt generate` and get a website, Nuxt.js generates `index.html` in dist folder.

So if I publish the website, I can simply access my website via `https://example.com/`.

Here comes my question, if I navigate to `https://example.com/index.html`, Nuxt.js immediately redirect my website to:

```
This page could not be found
Back to the home page
```

If I disable my browser JavaScript, I can access my website.

I've tried [Validate Method](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-validate#__layout), it's not working, I think it's because it's for dynamic routes, mine is a basic route.

How can I make Nuxt.js accept both `https://example.com/` and `https://example.com/index.html`?

Comment: Ever solve this? I am also trying to figure out how to allow both without needing to modify htaccess because its more of an application than a site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your routes in the underlying vue.js. How to configure see here:

```
 https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/
```

Watch that you make your project to "universal" instead "single page app" this has also implications.
 The basic problem here is one framework on top of another on top of a programming language.